# Name for table with metric_name and metric_value columns

Tags: database-design, pivot, terminology, unpivot

A typical database table might look something like this:

```
date-------geography---clicks---cost---conversions
___________________________________________________
1/1/2010---Kansas------56-------12-----1
```

When transposed, it looks like this.

```
date-----geography---metric_name---metric_value
____________________________________________
1/1/2010-Kansas------clicks--------56
1/1/2010-Kansas------cost----------12
1/1/2010-Kansas------conversions---1
```

The transposed table works better for some use cases where the number of metrics being collected changes frequently.

Is there a standard name for a table structured like that in the transposed table?

Answer (score 8):

## Unpivot Table

Being the product of a transformation, your desired form here is called an "*Unpivot table*". The form you're starting from here is either normalized data, or the result of a transformation itself called a [*"pivot."*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table)

You can pivot and unpivot without losing data. Pivoting and operations like this emerge from [OLAP functionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing), where they're rotations. In PostgreSQL we pivot with the [`tablefunc` module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html). We can easily *unpivot* with a `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` on a [`VALUES` list](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-values.html),

```
SELECT id, cat, value
FROM ( VALUES (1,1,2,3), (2,10,20,30) ) AS t1(id,x,y,z)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL ( VALUES ('X',x), ('Y',y), ('Z',z) ) 
  AS t2(cat, value);
```

Or, though slower, we use the `unnest(ARRAY[])` idiom and [*parallel unnest*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html)

```
SELECT id, cat, value
FROM ( VALUES (1,1,2,3), (2,10,20,30) ) AS t1(id,x,y,z)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(ARRAY['X','Y','Z'], ARRAY[x,y,z])
  AS t2(cat, value);
```

Either way you'll produce,

```
 id | cat | value 
----+-----+-------
  1 | X   |     1
  1 | Y   |     2
  1 | Z   |     3
  2 | X   |    10
  2 | Y   |    20
  2 | Z   |    30
(6 rows)
```

See also,

- [Unpivoting data in PostgreSQL (older method than used above)](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/283-Unpivoting-data-in-PostgreSQL.html)
- [Microsoft Technet docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [Oracle Pivot and Unpivot article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html)